# Submitting sitemap to Baidu

Tags: search-engines, sitemap, xml-sitemap, baidu

I've created a Baidu account to submit my `sitemap.xml` file to Baidu Search Console. I've also verified my phone number & email address. But when I try to submit my sitemap, they want the name as Chinese characters & QQ account number.

I'm not from China, how can I submit my sitemap to Baidu?

[image: Screenshot of Baidu Console requesting this information]

Comment: Are those fields not already completed - or is that just _placeholder_ text?

Comment: these are placeholder text